# Is Reflection the best way to determine the presense/absence of property/method on a dynamic object?

Tags: c#, dynamic, language-features

I have a number of data access methods that accept a dynamic object parameter (i.e., dynamic foo). I can't use an interface to define to type the input parameter due to existing code. I am setting properties in the data access methods, but using dynamic without checking to see if the properties/methods exist makes me nervous.

So I am looking for a way to check the runtime properties/methods of a dynamic object, but I would rather not use reflection due to the performance impact. Is there another/recommended way to query the properties/methods of a dynamic object?

Thanks,
Erick

Comment: You do not want to use reflection because of the performance impact, but are happy to use *dynamic*?

Comment: @Kirk: Dynamic actually performs surprisingly well.  It's quite a bit faster than reflection for accessing members...

Comment: You *think* they'll be a performance impact or you *know*? Design decisions are better made on facts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reflection doesn't actually work (the way you'd expect) on `dynamic` types.  You need to check for [`IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.idynamicmetaobjectprovider.aspx), then use its methods to determine whether a member is available on the type.

The problem is that it's perfectly acceptable for a `dynamic` type to add new members at runtime.  For an example, see [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx).  It only adds new members on set operations, but you can, just as easily, make a dynamic type that always returns a valid member, no matter what is passed into it, ie:

```
dynamic myType = new DynamicFoo();
Console.WriteLine(myType.Foo);
Console.WriteLine(myType.Bar);
Console.WriteLine(myType.Baz);
```

This can be done by overriding the get accessor, and just making them always valid.  In this case, reflection would have no way to tell what would work here...

Comment: Reed, this is the answer that I needed but I decided to take the approach of trying it and letting the exception get thrown. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would look at this problem a bit differently.  If you're using the objects with `dynamic` then whether or not the properties are accessible via reflection is irrelevant.  It only matters if they are accessible via `dynamic`.  So why not just use the properties and catch the execption that would result from their abscence?

Comment: +1 from me - this would be my approach.  Just use the object, and handle the exceptions as/if they come.

Comment: Jared, I think you are right. I always try to avoid exceptions, but this might be a good case to use one, as the absense of a property or method really should be an exceptional case.